# executeSql with WHERE clause not returning any results in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, sql, cordova

I am developing an application using Phonegap. I have created a table called location as follows:

```
...
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOCATIONS (id unique, name, key, secret)');
...
```

I inserted a row:

```
...
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOCATIONS (id, name, key, secret) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', [1, "Some Name", "Some Key", "Some Secret"], success, error);
...
```

When I do:

```
...
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM LOCATIONS', [ ], function(tx, results) {
  ...
}
```

I get results.rows.length equal to 1 and results.rows.item(0) is:

[ {"id":1,"name":"Some Name","key":"Some Key","secret":"Some Secret"} ]

However if I do:

```
...
function findById(id) {
  tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM LOCATIONS WHERE id = ?', [ id ], function(tx, results) {
    ...
  }
}
...
findById(1);
```

I get results.rows.length equal to 0 while I would expect it to be 1.

Has anyone experienced a similar problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got what the problem was. It seems when the row was inserted, the field "id" was created as an integer (since the value passed was an integer). However, when I was accessing findById, I was not sending 1, but I was sending "1" instead. The "WHERE" clause was expecting an integer and it was finding a String object instead.

It seems Web-SQL used in Phonegap does not give an error when you send an invalid type in a prepared statement (executeSql), but instead it returns 0 results. Strange behavior, but luckily I was able to solve my issue by parsing the integer:

function findById(id) {
  tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM LOCATIONS WHERE id = ?', [ parseInt(id) ], function(tx, results) {
    ...
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Results is an object, not an array. For example, if you want to access the name value you do `results.rows.item(0).name`. Similarly for the other columns.